# How can I use loop for JSON request/response with multiple similar parameters in Java?

Tags: java, android, json

Is there a way to put my request, and use my response in a loop when I've got very similar values? I thought about for loop but can't find a way to implement this.

I'm sending a request from Android device and there are `TextView` waiting for a response. When I got my response, I'm checking if it is not empty or null and if it's not, I'm setting text of `TextView` and changing visibility(because the default is gone).

For example this would be my `JSON`.

```
                {
                    spaghetti: [
                        {
                            strIngredient1: "1 pound ground beef",
                            strIngredient2: "1 onion, chopped",
                            strIngredient3: "null",
                            strIngredient4: "1 (28 ounce) can diced tomatoes",
                            strIngredient5: ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

And my condition:

```
                if(!"".equals(dinner.getStrIngredient1()) && !"null".equals(dish.getStrIngredient1())) {
                    firstIngredient.setText(dinner.getStrIngredient1());
                    firstIngredient.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if(!"".equals(dinner.getStrIngredient2()) && !"null".equals(dish.getStrIngredient2())) {
                    secondIngredient.setText(dinner.getStrIngredient2());
                    secondngredient.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                ...
```

As you can see above, I've got similar values and do I really need to repeat it five times? Is there way to make it "clean"?

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, or you can use switch case, But writings would be there so same.

Answer (score 0):

Use java Reflection.
But for that you need to tweak your firstIngredient, secondIngredient naming to ingredient1, ingredient2 respectively.

Get a for loop over your arraylist of Ingredients
Then use java reflection to form method dynamically

```
Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName);//in methodname you can write method you like to invoke like ingredient+i
method.invoke(obj, arg1, arg2);
```